# Linha do flexbox com espaço vazio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Eu estou desenvolvendo um blog pessoal. Na página de início, há um container com flexbox que exibe as postagens, como mostrado [nesta imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P2gK.png).

No entanto, estou tendo alguns problemas relativos à diagramação dessas postagens. Quando duas postagens em uma mesma linha possuem alturas diferentes, fica um espaço vazio, sendo que eu não desejo isso. Quero que esse espaço que sobrou seja preenchido pela postagem seguinte. Dessa forma, não ficaria nenhum espaço vazio, como mostrado [aqui neste desenho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdVwB.png).

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso utilizando flexbox?

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a sua pergunta e ler este post [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) antes de publicar, para que haja uma chance maior de outras pessoas poderem te ajudar e ser um post importante para a plataforma.